Why is my op-amp transient simulation showing negative gain while my AC simulation shows high gain?
Edit: Improved readability of schematics
I am testing a folded cascode op-amp I made. Here is the setup for my open-loop AC analysis:

The bode plot showed a gain of over 60 dB and BW about 3 kHz which was what I wanted.
Next I did a transient analysis in unity gain configuration like this:

That plot also showed what I wanted, with Vout = V+, no clipping.
Finally, I wanted to try to see a gain of 2 V/V, so I did this setup:

But instead of seeing Vout double the amplitude of Vin, I am getting Vout less than Vin:

Is there something wrong with the way I set up my 3rd test?

What's the Vcm and Vdd values?

Yuk! Red and orange on black is unreadable. Sorry!

I am guessing you disturbed the biasing of the OpAmp output stage by loading it with a 4k resistor to the ground. You may even have disturbed its small-signal output resistance in case it is an OTA.

@Designalog Vcm is 1.1V and Vdd is 2.4 V

@Transistor I replaced the unreadable images, thank you for letting me know

What is VCC connected to?

@SteKulov VCC is connected to a 2.4V DC voltage source

@charles I'm not too familiar with PSpice, but does the lack of dot here indicate there is no 3 branch connection?  https://i.sstatic.net/cWPtdurg.png

@SteKulov since the 3 branches all connect on one end of the resistor, there is no red dot. If I were to slide the bottom branch to the right, it would show a red dot, but it would make no difference in functionality.

@charles  OK, I wasn't sure with PSpice because in other CAD software I've seen that not be true so it was worth checking.  Anyway, if that's not the issue then the problem is likely with your implementation of the opamp.  Is there a way to see your subcircuit for the opamp or is it secret?  Also, have you tried higher VCC with higher input offsets to make the opamp operate further from the rails?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I would try to run the problematic circuit topology in DC and AC, and see if any of the DC voltages/current inside the op amp look different than the other configurations that work as expected. You can also try to bump up those resistors 100x to see if loading is the issue, as suggested in an earlier comment.

This is not negative gain, this is sub-unity gain. Negative gain would invert the signal.

The reason for the sub-unity (negative dB) gain was the 1k and 2k resistors were too small. I changed them to 100k and 200k, and then I saw a gain of 2 V/V in my transient simulation. Thank you @a360pilot and @Leo

So the internals of your opamp aren’t able to handle low K resistors? Is that due to your W and L of your MOSFETs?
